# Creating Graph API subscriptions with MailRead.Basic scope throws error on client credential flow

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks

An admin customer did consent to the following application permission scope (for all company) with a restriction on a mail enabled security group as mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) : `Calendars.Read MailboxSettings.Read Directory.Read.All Mail.ReadBasic Reports.Read.All`.

The authentication flows sends back this token, meaning authentication works :

```
[{"aud"=>"https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss"=>"https://sts.windows.net/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/",
  "iat"=>1607330778,
  "nbf"=>1607330778,
  "exp"=>1607334678,
  "aio"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "app_displayname"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "appid"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "appidacr"=>"2",
  "idp"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "idtyp"=>"app",
  "oid"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "rh"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "roles"=>["Calendars.Read", "MailboxSettings.Read", "Directory.Read.All", "Mail.ReadBasic", "Reports.Read.All"],
  "sub"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "tenant_region_scope"=>"EU",
  "tid"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "uti"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "ver"=>"1.0",
  "xms_tcdt"=>1356598049},
 {"typ"=>"JWT", "nonce"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "alg"=>"RS256", "x5t"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "kid"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}]
```

This token works to get message on a specific user, calling : `GET /users/{id}/messages`, meaning authentication token is valid for MailRead.Basic and this specific user.

The same token for the same user sends a 403 to subscribe a webhook on mailbox : `POST /subscriptions`

Body of the request :

```
{
   "changeType": "created",
   "notificationUrl": "XXXXXX",
   "resource": "users/{target_user_id}/messages",
   "expirationDateTime":"{relevant_timestamp}",
   "clientState": "secretClientValue",
   "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}
```

Answer form the Graph API :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ExtensionError",
        "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.]",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-12-07T09:15:54",
            "request-id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "client-request-id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share a screenshot of the permissions you added in AAD application.

Comment: Can you have a try with adding the application permission `Mail.Read`?

Comment: Could you please share the requestid and timestamp for this failed request?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity :  "date": "2020-12-07T10:06:19",
            "request-id": "806543c4-7ab4-41a0-88b5-071df22ee68f",
            "client-request-id": "806543c4-7ab4-41a0-88b5-071df22ee68f"

Comment: @AllenWu of course not ;). We use only MailRead.Basic scope with our customers for obvious security and confidentiality reasons.

Comment: Please share the timestamp as well.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity "date": "2020-12-07T10:06:19"

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity update : tested on a basic test app with one admin granted scope  : webhook subscription does work with an app permission for Mail.Read, not for Mail.ReadBasic ; everything being the same.

Comment: @AllenWu it does work on a test account with Mail.Read instead of Mail.ReadBasic. Is there anything else which should be modified in the request body ?

Comment: Nothing else you need to modified. Just add `Mail.Read` application permission into AAD application and do admin consent.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity any update about subscriptions to messages resource with Mail.ReadBasic scope, as mentioned in the table here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: @AllenWu the problem is that Microsoft Documentation mention that least proviledged Mail.ReadBasic is ok to subscribe to message resource. Just look at the table you will see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: I just found an official documentation mentionning the support on beta version since november 2019 : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changelog/?filterBy=Mail#f71da88e-acf6-486d-a7a1-244353344bccbeta . Still, with a MailRead.Basic.All scope granted, i get the same error message on beta endpoint. @ShivaKeshavVarma

Answer (score -1):

@Allen is right, according to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions):

> Creating a subscription requires read scope to the resource. For
> example, to get change notifications on messages, your app needs the
> Mail.Read permission.

[image]

Comment: But it is precisely mentioned that required scope for message subscriptions is Mail.Read or Mail.ReadBasic in the Microsoft documentation you shared. See here : "Depending on the resource and the permission type (delegated or application) requested, the permission specified in the following table is the least privileged required to call this API. " and the following table

Comment: @Sybic2001  Yes, the permissions listed in the document are from low to high, but to get the change notification of the message is more special, it requires you to have the highest permission. In addition, the document also has special instructions in a prominent place, you must have "Mail.Read" permission.

Comment: I clearly get your point, but it doesn't make sense : a notification sends only the ID of the element, which is completely compatible with a Mail.ReadBasic scope. So it still needs clarification from Microsoft ;) as both element are still referenced in the documentation. There is no logic in terms of priviledge to block subscriptions for Mail.ReadBasic scope.

Comment: @Sybic2001  Your logic is correct, but different api endpoints have different requirements for permissions. You cannot confuse them. Although the Microsoft document does not explain this in detail, it is still marked in a prominent position. It is recommended that you use The document shall prevail.